# How to undo all what is done by a colorbar() call (which is known to call the make_axes function)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, resize, colorbar

How does one restore a Matplotlib figure in its initial state before a colorbar creation ?

I want to use a single subplot that displays lines, curves, images, contours,etc, in a dynamical way depending on the actions of a user. So it can happen that at some point this subplot contains 3 images, then later no images, and then even later 2 images again, and so on. Each time a first image is added, a colorbar is created, whereas each time the last image is deleted, the colorbar is deleted and the subplot resized to its original size.

Here is a simple piece of code that tries to create the colorbar and then delete it and resize the plot several times. (for simplicity here, I don't play with the content of the 1st subplot) :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colorbar as cb
import numpy as np
import time
##
fig= plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
arr= np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])
im = ax.imshow(arr,interpolation='Nearest',origin='lower')
initialPosition=ax.get_position()
plt.show()
for i in range(5):
  cb =  plt.colorbar(im)           # here is the problem for i>1. ax is too small.
  fig.canvas.draw()
  time.sleep(2)
  # Try now to delete the colorbar and restore the initial size of ax
  fig.delaxes(fig.axes[1])         # first delete the colobar axes => OK
  ax.set_position(initialPosition) # then restore the size => OK
  fig.canvas.draw()
```

The behavior is strange: each time a new colorbar is created, the first subplot is smaller and smaller... I guess it has to do with the behavior of the make_axes() function called by colorbar(), which does not simply modify the position of the first subplot ax but also other properties of ax and/or fig.

Now another question, may be more important: Where a programmer is supposed to find this piece of information in the matplotlib official documentation?

Thanks for your help.

Denis

Comment: Why do you bother creating a colorbar only to delete it?

Comment: Actually, the first axes (subplot) is used for displaying different types of plots in a dynamical way, including images. The colobar is deleted and the subplot reset to its initial size as soon as no image are left in the elements to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you want to do this, but you can try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#
fig= plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
arr= np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])
im = ax.imshow(arr,interpolation='Nearest',origin='lower')
fig.canvas.draw() # draw the axis so we can get the right position
pos = ax.get_position() # backup the position before draw colorbar
cb=  plt.colorbar(im)
fig.canvas.draw()
fig.delaxes(fig.axes[1]) # first delete the colobar axes
ax.set_position(pos) #restore the position
plt.show()
```

**EDIT**

To restore colorbar, we need save the position of `ax` and `cb.ax` when the colorbar is visible:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colorbar as cb
import numpy as np
import time
##
fig= plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
arr= np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])
im = ax.imshow(arr,interpolation='Nearest',origin='lower')
fig.canvas.draw()
init_pos=ax.get_position()
cb =  plt.colorbar(im) 
fig.canvas.draw()
cb_pos = cb.ax.get_position()
ax_pos = ax.get_position()
fig.delaxes(fig.axes[1])
fig.canvas.draw()
plt.show()
for i in range(5):
    cb =  plt.colorbar(im)           # here is the problem for i>1. ax is too small.
    cb.ax.set_position(cb_pos)
    ax.set_position(ax_pos)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    time.sleep(2)
    # Try now to delete the colorbar and restore the initial size of ax
    fig.delaxes(fig.axes[1])         # first delete the colobar axes => OK
    ax.set_position(init_pos) # then restore the size => OK
    fig.canvas.draw()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: can you post some code that doesn't work by `set_position()`. the code I posted works on my PC.

Comment: Thanks HYRY. Actually it does not work for me as explained in the edited question above.

Comment: Thank you again HYRY. Your solution indeed works more or less like this, and solves my problem. However, it is not a very clean solution since it leaves in the figure and/or in the ax axes some properties indicating wrong sizes to be selected in the future, which we compensate for with several set_position() using our own memorized parameters (rather than relying on the parameters devoted to this). I should have better asked my question: "how to undo all what is done by a colorbar call (which is known to call the make_axes function)?"